# Questionlist regarding current status of LQG

Tags: discussion

on behalf of a small community of german scientists [physics & astrophysics, astronomy, not insiders in QG] and interested laymen I would like to compile a rather short questionlist regarding current status of LQG. The list should reflect current research topics [general questions, recent advances, major problems and open questions]. Our intention is not to start an own research program, it's just to get a brief overview and to understand better some arxiv papers.

Would it be OK for you a) to support us compiling such a list [suggestions from our side] and b) to answer the questions from your perspective?

Best regards
Tom

Comment: You may want eventually to cross-list this to — and also to support the proposal for — the [Theoretical Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23848/theoretical-physics) stack exchange site, which may also be a suitable place for such a compilation regarding current research into quantum gravity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I exactly understand what you have in mind. If you mean that you'd like to compile a list of questions and then get those questions answered on Physics Stack Exchange... it's certainly okay to ask the questions here (well, actually on [the main site](http://physics.stackexchange.com), not on this meta site), and hopefully people can answer them. But this would not be an appropriate place to post the list itself. You could, of course, compile a list of questions on a separate website if you want.

One thing you could do is look at the [quantum-gravity tag](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-gravity), which is an easy way to see all the questions that have been asked about quantum gravity. When you ask a question of your own, as long as you specify that tag when you ask the question, your question will show up in that list.

Comment: There is an LQG tag too ;-): http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop-quantum-gravity